# How we can organize different config profiles to use Quarkus profile in application.properties

Tags: quarkus

I have different profiles based on environment wise and needs to load it. How i can achieve and also how to pass program arguments for Quarkus main application to take dev profile(spring.config.location=classpath:/config/dev/application.yml)

Is there a way to load databse configuration while starting @QuarkusMain. I have configured all the database configurations into one class and how this class can be load in main. Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quarkus 1.13 (and later), supports profile aware `application.properties`. Just name your file `application-{profile}.properties` and activate it with `-Dquarkus.profile={profile}`

If you want to load specific files, you can also use `quarkus.config.locations`. This is backed by SmallRye Config. Please check additional documentation here: https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/main/config/config.html

Comment: Thanks Roberto Cortez for your reply, currently i am using 1.4.2.final version and set the profile using below two methods and going forward will upgrade to latest version.

1) QUARKUS_PROFILE = dev ( Environment variable)

2) System.setProperty("-Dquarkus.profile=dev")

Comment: How we can read secret in Linux file system using below configuration. I have tried below but its unable to read it. If you have any idea on this?

Ex:
username: test_app
password: FILE(/opt/pwd/app/appdb.pwd) --> secret is exists in this location but in Quarkus is failed to hanlde and read the secret.
any response much appreciated

Comment: The `quarkus.config.locations` can only read file properties files, yaml files, etc. Not sure about the format of the file you are trying to read.

Comment: Thanks Roberto.
Recently i have upgraded quarkus version from 1.4.2.final to 1.12.2.final and there is some issue with health check.

2021-05-03 09:54:50,883 INFO  [io.sma.health] (vert.x-worker-thread-13) 
SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {"status":"DOWN","checks":[{"name":"Database connections health check","status":"UP"},
{"name":"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check","status":"DOWN","data":{"openapi-psd2":"[OK]","generated-openapi-psd2":"[OK]","generated-openapi-groups":"[OK]","openapi-groups":"[KO]"}}]}
any idea why this is occuring after upgrade?

Comment: Please, open a separate question for that issue, since is not related with configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Roberto. I have raised seperate question for this. Please check and respond. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385775/readinessprobe-is-failed-in-quarkus-1-12-2-final-version

Comment: Roberto Cortez: i have upgraded to latest version of quarkus (version : 1.13.3.final) when ever we hit swagger URL its appending /q and same for health endpoints as well. Is there a way to disable appending /q before swagger and health points.

ex: 
health endpoint readiness : /health/ready
health endpoint liveness : /health/live

but it's appeding extra /q in url due to that some logic is not working and can't add /q.
 /q/health/ready, /q/health/live.

Comment: The `q` was added to avoid polluting the application root path with quarkus extensions path that could cause clashing. Please check: https://quarkus.io/blog/path-resolution-in-quarkus/

Comment: Updated smallrye url: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/Main/config-sources/locations/#use-smallrye-config-in-a-java-application