# Readinessprobe is failed in Quarkus 1.12.2.final version

Tags: quarkus

Recently i have upgraded quarkus version from 1.4.2.final to 1.12.2.final and there is some issue with health check.

2021-05-03 09:54:50,883 INFO [io.sma.health] (vert.x-worker-thread-13) SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {"status":"DOWN","checks":[{"name":"Database connections health check","status":"UP"}, {"name":"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check","status":"DOWN","data":{"openapi-psd2":"[OK]","generated-openapi-psd2":"[OK]","generated-openapi-groups":"[OK]","openapi-groups":"[KO]"}}]}

any idea why this is occuring after upgrade?

Comment: The error says it all: the `SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check` health check reports `DOWN`, because `openapi-groups` reports `KO`. I don't know what `openapi-groups` is, but that's what you should check.

Comment: i have figured it out and fixed the issue and could you please tell me how to add named datasource without any default datasource, is it possible, if yes please share sample snippet of configuration.


quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.password=quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=8
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=2